# Linq select specific last records

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I new developer for linq and sql server.
I know oracle and pl/sql
how I can write this query in linq
Oracle :

```
select * from (select * from table order by createDate) where rownum<500
```

Comment: Even if new.... you should show what you have tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = db.Table.OrderBy(x => x.createDate).Take(499);
```

Comment: @alettin - if Tim has solved your problem, be a pal and accept his answer :)

Comment: @alettin:  What Brett wanted to tell you is, there is a check mark beside the answer. Look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)